# Swift 5: how to update multiple labels from one button press

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making a simple app to calculate quantities for my bread baking. I have multiple "Button"s to change the variables, however the Labels displaying those values aren't refreshing when I press them.

Any button should trigger a refresh of almost all labels, because the math will change each one.

Example: Adding 50g of flour will affect the quantity of water, salt, and yeast. Changing a percentage of water would affect only the quantity of water needed.

Thanks,

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

var flourPercent = 100
var waterPercent = 70
var saltPercent =  6.0
var yeastPercent = 2.0

var flourQuantity = 1000
var waterQuantity = flourQuantity * waterPercent / 100
var saltQuantity = flourQuantity * Int(saltPercent) / 100
var yeastQuantity = flourQuantity * Int(yeastPercent) / 100

let yeastStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(yeastPercent*100)/100)

struct ContentView: View {


var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Label("Subtract", systemImage: "")
            Button(action: {
                flourQuantity -= 50
                print(flourQuantity)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                waterPercent -= 1
                print(waterPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                saltPercent -= 1
                print(saltPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                yeastPercent -= 0.1
                print(yeastPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Add", systemImage: "")
            Button(action: {
                flourQuantity += 50
                print(flourQuantity)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                waterPercent += 1
                print(waterPercent)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                saltPercent += 1
                print(saltPercent)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                yeastPercent += 0.1
                print(yeastPercent)
                
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Baker's %", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(flourPercent)%", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(waterPercent)%", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(Int(saltPercent))%", systemImage: "")
            Label(yeastStr + "%", systemImage: "")
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Quantity", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(flourQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(waterQuantity)ml", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(saltQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(yeastQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can make this work with very few updates to your code. The properties you use to generate the text for your labels, have to be `@State` properties. This means whenever one of them is modified the view is redrawn:

```
import SwiftUI

@State var flourPercent: CGFloat = 100
@State var waterPercent: CGFloat = 70
@State var saltPercent: CGFloat =  6.0
@State var yeastPercent: CGFloat = 2.0

var flourQuantity: CGFloat = 1000
var waterQuantity: CGFloat = { flourQuantity * waterPercent / 100 }
var saltQuantity: CGFloat = { flourQuantity * Int(saltPercent) / 100 }
var yeastQuantity: CGFloat = { flourQuantity * Int(yeastPercent) / 100 }

let yeastStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(yeastPercent*100)/100)

struct ContentView: View {


var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Label("Subtract", systemImage: "")
            Button(action: {
                flourQuantity -= 50
                print(flourQuantity)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                waterPercent -= 1
                print(waterPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                saltPercent -= 1
                print(saltPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
            Button(action: {
                yeastPercent -= 0.1
                print(yeastPercent)
            }) {
                Text("-")
            }
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Add", systemImage: "")
            Button(action: {
                flourQuantity += 50
                print(flourQuantity)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                waterPercent += 1
                print(waterPercent)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                saltPercent += 1
                print(saltPercent)
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
            Button(action: {
                yeastPercent += 0.1
                print(yeastPercent)
                
            }) {
                Text("+")
            }
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Baker's %", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(flourPercent)%", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(waterPercent)%", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(Int(saltPercent))%", systemImage: "")
            Label(yeastStr + "%", systemImage: "")
        }
        VStack {
            Label("Quantity", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(flourQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(waterQuantity)ml", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(saltQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
            Label("\(yeastQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I just prependes each variable that you change by the property wrapper @State. Read more about it here:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-state-property-wrapper

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about the @State property. I'm getting a few errors with these solutions, mostly due to the following type of error: "Cannot use instance member 'flourQuantity' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

But I think I get what I have to do to fix that. I think I'm on the right track now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah your *quantity properties are typical computed properties since they can be computed from you other properties. You have to declare them like this: `var yeastQuantity: CGFloat = { flourQuantity * Int(yeastPercent) / 100 }`. Especially they are no property wrappers. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@State` property wrapper to track changes in real time to your variables. The changes will be reflected on-screen when the buttons are pressed:

```
import SwiftUI

var flourPercent = 100
var waterPercent = 70
var saltPercent =  6.0
var yeastPercent = 2.0

let yeastStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(yeastPercent*100)/100)

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var flourQuantity = 1000
    @State var waterQuantity: Int = 0
    @State var saltQuantity: Int = 0
    @State var yeastQuantity: Int = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Label("Subtract", systemImage: "")
                Button(action: {
                    flourQuantity -= 50
                    print(flourQuantity)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    waterPercent -= 1
                    print(waterPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    saltPercent -= 1
                    print(saltPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    yeastPercent -= 0.1
                    print(yeastPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Add", systemImage: "")
                Button(action: {
                    flourQuantity += 50
                    print(flourQuantity)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    waterPercent += 1
                    print(waterPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    saltPercent += 1
                    print(saltPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    yeastPercent += 0.1
                    print(yeastPercent)
                    
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Baker's %", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(flourPercent)%", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(waterPercent)%", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(Int(saltPercent))%", systemImage: "")
                Label(yeastStr + "%", systemImage: "")
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Quantity", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(flourQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(waterQuantity)ml", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(saltQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(yeastQuantity)g", systemImage: "")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.waterQuantity = flourQuantity * waterPercent / 100
            self.saltQuantity = flourQuantity * Int(saltPercent) / 100
            self.yeastQuantity = flourQuantity * Int(yeastPercent) / 100
        })
    }
}
```

There are some slight changes to your code here.. note the location of the declaration of the @State variable. This is just a quick example to show how it works, you will need to tweak it to do what you want. I set the initial values in the onAppear tag near the bottom...

***Updated answer***

- Answer using Published Var's - So for what you are trying to, I think it would be better to use Environment Variables as shown below. I only set it up to work on the FlourQty, but from my example, you can see how it works..

1 - Define an ObservableObject class

2 - Publish your variables in that class

3 - ***IMPORTANT*** - Add the variable of the Environment to your ContentView Class in the SceneDelegate:

```
 let myQty = QtyEnv()

 let contentView = ContentView()
    .environmentObject(myQty)
```

Then this new example will work. I have also changed the calculations to change when it detects the FlourQty has changed..

```
import SwiftUI

//create the observable object class - dont forget to add to sceneDelegate..
final class QtyEnv:ObservableObject {
    @Published var flourQty = 0
    @Published var saltQty = 0
    @Published var waterQty = 0
    @Published var yeastQty = 0
}


var flourPercent = 100
var waterPercent = 70
var saltPercent =  6.0
var yeastPercent = 2.0

let yeastStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(yeastPercent*100)/100)

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var myQty: QtyEnv
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Label("Subtract", systemImage: "")
                Button(action: {
                    self.myQty.flourQty -= 50
                    print(myQty.flourQty)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    waterPercent -= 1
                    print(waterPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    saltPercent -= 1
                    print(saltPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    yeastPercent -= 0.1
                    print(yeastPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("-")
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Add", systemImage: "")
                Button(action: {
                    self.myQty.flourQty += 50
                    print(myQty.flourQty)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    waterPercent += 1
                    print(waterPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    saltPercent += 1
                    print(saltPercent)
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    yeastPercent += 0.1
                    print(yeastPercent)
                    
                }) {
                    Text("+")
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Baker's %", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(flourPercent)%", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(waterPercent)%", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(Int(saltPercent))%", systemImage: "")
                Label(yeastStr + "%", systemImage: "")
            }
            VStack {
                Label("Quantity", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(self.myQty.flourQty)g", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(self.myQty.waterQty)ml", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(self.myQty.saltQty)g", systemImage: "")
                Label("\(self.myQty.yeastQty)g", systemImage: "")
            }
        }
        
//adjust published vars when changes of flourQty detected:
        .onReceive(self.myQty.$flourQty, perform: { _ in
            self.myQty.waterQty = self.myQty.flourQty * waterPercent / 100
            self.myQty.saltQty = self.myQty.flourQty * Int(saltPercent) / 100
            self.myQty.yeastQty = self.myQty.flourQty * Int(yeastPercent) / 100
        })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I've got half of this working as intended, but now I just have to figure out how to update the Quantity labels when these values change.

Thinking about it more, is the @state property is only triggering the label to change that single property. But I need to change all the labels to reflect the math. i.e. Changing the flourQuantity will change the waterQuantity, the saltQuantity, yeastQuantity, etc.

Do I need to wrap these in a larger class or something?

Thanks!

Comment: I've added a second example using Environment Variable which may be more suited to your application. I only made it trigger on the flourQty, but with that example, you should be able to apply that concept to what you are trying to do.